# Why <a> tag doesn't fit to child image

Tags: html, css, browser, web

I've got a header like that:

```
<header id="top">

        <a id="logourl" href="/"><img src="/images/logo.jpg" alt="LOGO" id="logo"></a>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li id="firstli"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/machines">Macchine</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/resellers">Rivenditori</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/where">Dove siamo</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/contact">Contatti</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

With the CSS:

```
header{
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-webkit-flex;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
     align-items: center;
    width:100%;

    background-color: #3498DB;

}



#logo{

    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 20%;
}

#logourl{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: block;


}

header nav {
    width: auto;
    /*-webkit-align-self: flex-end;
        -ms-flex-item-align: end;
    align-self: flex-end;*/
    margin-bottom: 20px;

}
header nav ul{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
     -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    /*justify-content: space-between;*/
    -webkit-flex-wrap:wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap:wrap;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}


header nav li {

    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    /*border-right: 2px solid white;*/
    /*border-radius: 10px;*/
    /*margin-right: 10px;*/
    color: white;
    margin-left: 20px;

}header nav li>a {
    margin:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #F2F1EF;
    font-weight: bolder;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 25px;
    }

header nav li>a:hover{
    color: white;


}
```

The problem is that the "a" tag should fit to image size, but that's not true, because it stretches from the left to the middle of the page width, so some nav menu entries wrap to a new even in full screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this css:

```
#logourl{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear how this is supposed to look but just setting `display:flex` on the parent doesn't automatically tell the children how to behave.

I saw a width of 20% in there which I assume was mean to be for the logo *area* (not the logo image)....so that receives `flex:0 0 20%;`

The nav therefore should be `flex:1` to take up the remaining space.

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/rOjOmg)

You will, of course, require media queries at some point to avoid any unwanted wrapping.

```css
header {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #3498DB;
}
#logo {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
#logourl {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 20%;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 20%;
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  text-align: center;
}
header nav {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  /*-webkit-align-self: flex-end;
        -ms-flex-item-align: end;
    align-self: flex-end;*/
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
header nav ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  /*justify-content: space-between;*/
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
header nav li {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  /*border-right: 2px solid white;*/
  /*border-radius: 10px;*/
  /*margin-right: 10px;*/
  color: white;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
header nav li>a {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #F2F1EF;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 25px;
}
header nav li>a:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header id="top">

  <a id="logourl" href="/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-c-250-100-10.jpg" alt="LOGO" id="logo">
  </a>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li id="firstli"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/machines">Macchine</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/resellers">Rivenditori</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/where">Dove siamo</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/contact">Contatti</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```